# How can I prove that $10=2^{a}*3^{b}*7^{c}$ has infinite solutions?

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation, nonlinear-system

Both in a unrescrited case and with the following restriction:
$a+b+c=1$

Answer (score 0):

For the unrestricted case, let $a=1.$  Now you need
$3^b7^c=5$, so for a positive integer $n$, let

$$3^b = 5^{n+1}, 7^c = 5^{-n}$$.

Solve these two equations for $b$ and $c$.

That should give you a leg up on the restricted case.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** 
$$c=1-a-b$$

Your equation then becomes
$$\frac{10}{7}=(\frac{2}{7})^a (\frac{3}{7})^b$$

Show now that if you fix $a$ you can find some $b$ which satisfies this equation.